# drawing a line on linegraph on mouseover?

Tags: d3.js

I am building a line graph with D3.js. When the user mouses over the graph, I would like to draw a vertical line on the graph, highlight its intersection with the chart lines, and show a tooltip, like this screenshot:

[image]

I have got part of the way down this road. Here is my code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BvuBV/1/

As you can see, I am listening for mouse events on the `svg` element, and the line is (sort of) displaying correctly:

```
// Add mouseover events.
svg.on("mouseover", function() { 
  console.log('mouseover')
}).on("mousemove", function() {
  console.log('mousemove', d3.mouse(this));
  var x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
  hoverLine.attr("x1", x).attr("x2", x).style("opacity", 1);
}).on("mouseout", function() {
  console.log('mouseout');
  hoverLine.style("opacity", 1e-6);
});
```

However, there are a couple of problems:

1. The `mouseover` and `mousemove` events don't seem to fire consistently when I mouse over the SVG element, only sometimes - am I doing something wrong?
2. I don't know how to translate the `x` and `y` values provided by `d3.mouse(this)` back into date and `inlet` values, so that I can draw the desired circles on the graph, and show the desired popup.

Any help is very much appreciated.

UPDATE: Thanks to help from @Aegis I have solved 1 and part of 2: http://jsfiddle.net/BvuBV/4/

But I still don't know how to highlight the intersection of the hover line with the two chart lines, and how to retrieve the values of the chart lines at that point.

Comment: I'm researching the same thing and I think I'm about where you are with this problem. I do notice one thing that should be able to help your chart some, though. Don't bother messing with opacity through JS. Just do it in CSS:


    .hover-line { opacity: 0; }
    .air-quality:hover .hover-line { opacity: 1; }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help you to get a bit further (I have no experience with D3 at all):

1. For some reason your events are bound to the paths, not the base svg element. If you do `d3.select(".air-quality").on(..)` it seems to work as you would expect.

Comment: ... now I just need to figure out how to get from the x- and y- coordinates to the other values...

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an option for that though? It seems like the kind of feature that would be embedded.

Comment: There's `scale.invert` which lets you translate the mouse x and y into graph x and y - so I can get part of the way there http://jsfiddle.net/BvuBV/4/ But I'm not sure how to highlight the intersection of the hover line and the chart lines.

Comment: Oh no I meant: isn't there an option to display this kind of vertical line?

Answer (score 14):

I know this has already been marked as answered, but for future googlers for whom this shows up as a top result... A working example for a vertical line on mouseover can be found here: http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136

Here's the relevant portion of the code for the vertical line:

```
  var vertical = d3.select(".chart")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "remove")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "19")
        .style("width", "1px")
        .style("height", "380px")
        .style("top", "10px")
        .style("bottom", "30px")
        .style("left", "0px")
        .style("background", "#fff");

  d3.select(".chart")
      .on("mousemove", function(){  
         mousex = d3.mouse(this);
         mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
         vertical.style("left", mousex + "px" )})
      .on("mouseover", function(){  
         mousex = d3.mouse(this);
         mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
         vertical.style("left", mousex + "px")});
```