# d3.js:vertical moving line's intersection point with line graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am using d3 library for plotting line graph.

Following is my code to generate line chart.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Line Graph using SVG and d3.js</title>
    <script src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* tell the SVG path to be a thin blue line without any area fill */
        path {
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1;
            fill: none;
        }

        .axis {
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .x.axis line {
            stroke: lightgrey;
        }

        .x.axis .minor {
            stroke-opacity: .5;
        }

        .x.axis path {
            display: none;
        }

        .y.axis line, .y.axis path {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="graph" class="aGraph" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0; float:left;"></div>


    <script>
        /* implementation heavily influenced by http://bl.ocks.org/1166403 */

        // define dimensions of graph
        var m = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
        var w = 1000 - m[1] - m[3]; // width
        var h = 400 - m[0] - m[2]; // height

        // create a simple data array that we'll plot with a line (this array represents only the Y values, X will just be the index location)
        var data = [3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 2, 0, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 9, 3, 6, 3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 2, 1, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 9, 2, 7];

        // X scale will fit all values from data[] within pixels 0-w
        var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, w]);
        // Y scale will fit values from 0-10 within pixels h-0 (Note the inverted domain for the y-scale: bigger is up!)
        var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([h, 0]);
        // automatically determining max range can work something like this
        // var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([h, 0]);

        // create a line function that can convert data[] into x and y points
        var line = d3.svg.line()
                // assign the X function to plot our line as we wish
                .x(function(d, i) {
                    // verbose logging to show what's actually being done
                    console.log('Plotting X value for data point: ' + d + ' using index: ' + i + ' to be at: ' + x(i) + ' using our xScale.');
                    // return the X coordinate where we want to plot this datapoint
                    return x(i);
                })
                .y(function(d) {
                    // verbose logging to show what's actually being done
                    console.log('Plotting Y value for data point: ' + d + ' to be at: ' + y(d) + " using our yScale.");
                    // return the Y coordinate where we want to plot this datapoint
                    return y(d);
                })

        // Add an SVG element with the desired dimensions and margin.
        var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
                .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

        // create yAxis
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(true);
        // Add the x-axis.
        graph.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
                .call(xAxis);


        // create left yAxis
        var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(4).orient("left");
        // Add the y-axis to the left
        graph.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
                .call(yAxisLeft);

        // Add the line by appending an svg:path element with the data line we created above
        // do this AFTER the axes above so that the line is above the tick-lines
        graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));

        var line1 = graph.append('line')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(100, 50)')
                .attr({'x1': 0, 'y1': 0, 'x2': 0, 'y2': 1400})
                .attr('class', 'selection_line');
        graph.on('mousemove', function(e) {
            var navigatorVersion = navigator.appVersion;
            var navigatorAgent = navigator.userAgent;
            var browserName = navigator.appName;
            var fullVersionName = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
            var majorVersionName = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
            var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;
            // In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox" 
            //To make line scroll horizontally in mozilla firefox use following code       
            if ((verOffset = navigatorAgent.indexOf("Firefox")) != -1) {
                browserName = "Firefox";
                fullVersionName = navigatorAgent.substring(verOffset + 8);
            }
            if (browserName == "Firefox") {
                line1.attr("x1", d3.event.clientX - 100);
                line1.attr("x2", d3.event.clientX - 100);
            }
            else {
                line1.attr("x1", d3.event.x - 100);
                line1.attr("x2", d3.event.x - 100);
            }
        });



    </script>



</body>
 </html>
```

on mouse move i want to move one vertical line with mouse and want to find intersection point of vertical line with line graph. ie find x and y coordinate of line graph where vertical line intersects graph.

Any idea why is it not working?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882642/d3-js-drawing-a-line-on-linegraph-on-mouseover) should help.

Comment: That error, without any context, doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: it is due to this line i think. var div_width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width').replace('px', ''));

Comment: Ok, so have you tried replacing that line to see if that makes it work?

Comment: i have tried removing these  2 lines var div_width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width').replace('px',''));
var graph_width = (div_width > 695) ? div_width: 695;  error is gone but graph is not displayed

Comment: i loaded script in body tag and issue resolved

Comment: Fiddle with original code: http://jsfiddle.net/7hXgw/2/

Comment: how to plot two separate graphs and find intersection point of vertical line with both graphs?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BvuBV/4/ code in this fiddle is getting y axis data of mouse position but I want to find out intersection point of vertical line with graph(intersection point of red line and vertical line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is working version of your graph with lots of changes - http://jsfiddle.net/cuckovic/vKe67/

And here is the code that does "heavy lifting":

```
rect.on('mousemove', function () {

var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0];
d3.select(".verticalLine").attr("transform", function () {
    return "translate(" + xPos + ",0)";
});


var pathLength = mainLine.node().getTotalLength();
var x = xPos;
var beginning = x,
    end = pathLength,
    target;
while (true) {
    target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
    pos = mainLine.node().getPointAtLength(target);
    if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== x) {
        break;
    }
    if (pos.x > x) end = target;
    else if (pos.x < x) beginning = target;
    else break; //position found
}
circle.attr("opacity", 1)
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", pos.y);


console.log("x and y coordinate where vertical line intersects graph: " + [pos.x, pos.y]);
console.log("data where vertical line intersects graph: " + [xScale.invert(pos.x), yScale.invert(pos.y)]);
});
```

Regards,
Igor

Comment: how to find intersection point if i have two graphs and one single vertical line is crossing both of them i want to find out intersection point of vertical line with both the graphs http://jsfiddle.net/2SURM/

Comment: It could be done by putting this second graph on the same "rect" element below the first graph an then modify all variables that are used in calculations. Basically you have to duplicate the first graph.

Comment: @cukovic can u pls explain what is actually happening in target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
    pos = mainLine.node().getPointAtLength(target);
    if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== x) {
        break;
    }
    if (pos.x > x) end = target;
    else if (pos.x < x) beginning = target;
    else break; //position found this part of code?